# Wordpress issue after updateing to newest version

Tags: php, wordpress

I updated to the newest wordpress version and it shows this error

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /srv/disk2/2682915/www/naimiregllazhe.com/wp-content/themes/woodmart/functions.php on line 73
```

Comment: its not the error in wordpress but seems to be in your theme, change `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Install the latest version of the theme.

Comment: Thank u .. that worked for me!